# What are the mahāyāga and rahoyāga kramas that are mentioned in the śrī lalitā sahasranāma stotra?

Tags: tantra, lalita, lalita-sahasranama

In śrī lalitā sahasranāma stotra, we come across the names *mahāyāga-kramārādhyā* (230) [[1]](https://archive.org/details/SriLalitaSahasranamamDr.CSuryanayanamuthy/page/62/mode/1up) [[2]](https://archive.org/details/sri-lalita-sahasranamam-with-meanings-and-commentary-in-english-n-ramamurthy/page/287/mode/1up) [[3]](https://archive.org/details/dli.ernet.54343/page/137/mode/1up) and *rahoyāga-kramārādhyā* (381) [[4]](https://archive.org/details/SriLalitaSahasranamamDr.CSuryanayanamuthy/page/82/mode/1up) [[5]](https://archive.org/details/sri-lalita-sahasranamam-with-meanings-and-commentary-in-english-n-ramamurthy/page/360/mode/1up) [[6]](https://archive.org/details/dli.ernet.54343/page/208/mode/1up). Are there any texts which point to the mahāyāga and rahoyāga krama/paths/processes?

Any information on these two paths would be helpful!

Comment: I would suggest to read Bhaskararaya's commentary on it.